# A solution to rEFInd unable to load using shim when Secure Boot is enabled

Tags: linux, shim, refind

### Background

Ubuntu 21.10 can load on my computer through secure boot, and the shim version is 15.4. Then refer to the official [tutorial](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#shim), I installed rEFInd v0.13.2 (the latest version when I posted this blog) via PPA in Ubuntu 21.10. However, when I restart the system and load rEFInd, it always fails with the message `Verification failed:(0x1A)Security Violation`. I'm sure that both `refind_local.cer` and `refind.cer` under the `EFI/refind/keys/` have been enrolled through `MokManager` (Although only `refind_local.cer` is needed through PPA installation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Cause

From [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/c54261c145/), I got that rEFInd currently (v0.13.2) lacks the `.sbat` section. For shim 15.3 and later versions, [SBAT](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/main/SBAT.md) is mandatory, resulting in failure to start rEFInd.

The post also indicates that the author of rEFInd is currently studying how to solve the related problems. I hope the later versions can fix this issue.

### Solution

To conclude, you need to use shim 15 to solve this problem. For this purpose, you can perform the following steps (applicable to amd64. Steps are also similar if you are on other architectures):

1. Obtain MokManager and the shim efi file signed by Microsoft from [Ubuntu launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu). To achieve this, download [shim_15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/469850621/shim_15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and [shim-signed_1.45+15+1552672080-064ubuntub_bed64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/502909051/shim-signed_1.45+15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb).
2. Unpack the downloaded [shim_15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/469850621/shim_15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and take out the `mmx64.efi` file. (`data.tar.xz`-> `.` -> `usr/lib/shim/mmx64.efi`)
3. Unpack the download [shim-signed_1.45+15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/502909051/shim-signed_1.45+15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb), take out the `shimx64.efi.dualsigned` file. (`data.tar.xz`-> `.` -> `usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.dualsigned`) Rename it to `shimx64.efi`.
4. Go to download [refind-bin-0.13.2.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.13.2/refind-bin-0.13.2.zip/download).  Then create a new folder, and put the two files taken out together with the downloaded zip file into the new folder.
5. Open terminal in the fore-mentioned folder, then execute the following commands:

```sh
unzip refind-bin-0.13.2.zip
cd refind-bin-0.13.2
sudo ./refind-install --shim ../shimx64.efi
```

If you encounter any confirmation during the installation process, just enter `y` to confirm.

6. After restarting, if it prompts `Verification failed`, refer to step 9 of the official [tutorial](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#shim). Select  `Enroll key from disk`, and then select the ESP disk where you installed rEFInd. Finally, choose the file of path `EFI/refind/keys/refind.cer` to import.
7. If you use a non-Ubuntu Linux system on your computer, you can continue to import the cer files corresponding to your distributions in `EFI/refind/keys` as above. Failure to do so may cause your Linux distribution to be unable to boot via rEFInd.

Comment: Linux Mint already uses shim 15. Anyway, I tried upgrading to the one from Ubuntu and it didn't work.